# Jenkins installation automation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible

**Old Question**
Is that possible to automate Jenkins installation(Jenkins binaries, plugins, credentials) by using any of the configuration management automation tool like Ansible and etc?

**Edited**
After this question asked I have learned and found many ways to achieve Jenkins Installation. I found docker-compose is interesting to achieve one way of Jenkins Installation automation. So my question is, Is there a better way to automate Jenkins Installation than I am doing, Is there any risk in the way I am handling this automation.

I have taken the advantage of docker Jenkins image and did the automation with docker-compose

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins kubernetes workflow-aggregator git configuration-as-code blueocean matrix-auth
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dind:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    networks:
      jenkins:
        aliases:
        - docker
    expose:
    - "2376"
    environment:
    - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: jenkins-home
      target: /var/jenkins_home  
    - type: volume
      source: jenkins-docker-certs
      target: /certs/client
  
  jcac:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./jcac.yml
      target: /usr/share/nginx/html/jcac.yml
    networks:
    - jenkins

  jenkins:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "50000:50000"
    environment:
    - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
    - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
    - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    - JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"
    - CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG=http://jcac/jcac.yml
    - GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN:-fake}
    - GITHUB_USERNAME=${GITHUB_USERNAME:-fake}
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: jenkins-home
      target: /var/jenkins_home
    - type: volume
      source: jenkins-docker-certs
      target: /certs/client
      read_only: true
    networks:
    - jenkins
volumes:
  jenkins-home:
  jenkins-docker-certs:
networks:
  jenkins:
```

jcac.yaml

```
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
      - credentials:
        - usernamePassword:
            id: "github"
            password: ${GITHUB_PASSWORD:-fake}
            scope: GLOBAL
            username: ${GITHUB_USERNAME:-fake}
        - usernamePassword:
            id: "slave"
            password: ${SSH_PASSWORD:-fake}
            username: ${SSH_USERNAME:-fake}

jenkins:
  globalNodeProperties:
  - envVars:
      env:
      - key: "BRANCH"
        value: "hello"
  systemMessage: "Welcome to (one click) Jenkins Automation!"
  agentProtocols:
    - "JNLP4-connect"
    - "Ping"
  crumbIssuer:
    standard:
      excludeClientIPFromCrumb: true
  disableRememberMe: false
  markupFormatter: "plainText"
  mode: NORMAL
  myViewsTabBar: "standard"
  numExecutors: 4
  # nodes:
  #   - permanent:
  #       labelString: "slave01"
  #       launcher:
  #         ssh:
  #           credentialsId: "slave"
  #           host: "worker"
  #           port: 22
  #           sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy: "nonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy"
  #       name: "slave01"
  #       nodeDescription: "SSH Slave 01"
  #       numExecutors: 3
  #       remoteFS: "/home/jenkins/workspace"
  #       retentionStrategy: "always"
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      enableCaptcha: false
      users:
        - id: "admin"
          password: "${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin123}" #
        - id: "user"
          password: "${DEFAULTUSER_PASSWORD:-user123}"
  authorizationStrategy:
    globalMatrix:
      permissions:
      - "Agent/Build:user"
      - "Job/Build:user"
      - "Job/Cancel:user"
      - "Job/Read:user"
      - "Overall/Read:user"
      - "View/Read:user"
      - "Overall/Read:anonymous"
      - "Overall/Administer:admin"
      - "Overall/Administer:root"
unclassified:
 globalLibraries:
    libraries:
    - defaultVersion: "master"
      implicit: false
      name: "jenkins-shared-library"
      retriever:
        modernSCM:
          scm:
            git:
              remote: "https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/jenkins-shared-libs.git"
              traits:
              - "gitBranchDiscovery"
```

**The command to start and stop Jenkins are**

```
# start Jenkins
docker-compose up -d

# stop Jenkins
docker-compose down
```

Comment: For plugins : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_plugin_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is :) For Ansible you can always check [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com) whenever you want to automate installation of something. [Here is the most popular role for installing Jenkins](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/jenkins). And [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-jenkins) is its GitHub repo